# What is the best method for mapping multiple point datasets with filters?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have 5 point datasets and 1 polygon dataset. I want to map them and have checkboxes to filter each dataset by 2 fields each.

What is the best method, or available template?  I would like to use geojson or csv for data.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be not to strain your client with that task but to have some sort of API which returns the filtered results. Generate requests for your datasets based on your inputs, for example: `/api/dataset/1?foo=true&bar=false` or `/api/dataset/3?foo=false&bar=true` and then let your server return the appropriate results. That way your client doesn't have to download the entire resultsets, when they might not be needed (which is faster) and doesn't have to do the filtering (which is slower). You application will feel much quicker and more responsive that way.